# How to get Global list into HTML dropdown

Tags: arrays, dropdown, global, sidebar

I am trying to create a dropdown in the google sheets sidebar that is linked to the list in the globals.gs so it is not hard coded in the html. anyone have any suggestions on how to this or where to look for guidance?

[image]

I have looked but can't find anything except where it is linked to a range in the sheet and not in the globals.